# Как в меню вставлять иконки?

Tags: drupal

Добрый день.
Подскажите, люди добрые, у меня меню выводится списком `<ul>`, как настроить `Drupal 7` таким образом, чтобы можно было в пункт меню `li` вставлять нужный мне `img src`?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[Menu Icons](https://drupal.org/project/menu_icons)